Prevent VS code "skipping" quote keypress if next char is a quote
In VS code when the cursor is placed in front of a quote character, and you press that same character on your keyboard, instead of inserting a character as you would expect it just positions the cursor after the already existing quote character.  I want to disable this behavior and instead, insert the quote that I typed, but I cannot find a setting to do this.
I've searched the settings for "auto", "quote", and a few other keywords and wasn't able to find anything.
Added note: It does this with brackets and parenthesis as well, which I would also like to disable.  It's not quote specific so it's likely not in the quotes related settings.

Check the editor.autoClosingOvertype setting.  By default, it should be set to auto.  You want to set it to never:

{
  "editor.autoClosingOvertype": "never"
}


Perfect, thanks!  Who knew  "closing" would also affect "opening".
